# how to change next element background color from parent element id, jquery

Tags: jquery

background color ?, if we know 
`<li id="li508e1d87e91d040750687eef">` id value

```
 <li id="li508e1d87e91d040750687eef" style="background-color: rgb(0, 118, 163);">
        <span >
        Skill044
        <a onclick="OnBtnShowPopupClick(this.id);" id="508e1d87e91d040750687eef">Edit</a>
        <span class="Experience" id="Exp508e1d87e91d040750687eef">4</span>
        </span>
    </li>
```

Comment: Where in the world are you getting those ID strings from, anyway?

Comment: @idk Don't forget to add a space in the selector: `$("#li" + idNo + " span:first");` before `span`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector in the following way:

```
var span = $("#li" + idNo + " span:first");
span.css("background-color", "#790000");
```

Comment: you forgot the space before `span:first`, it is important

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `id` of the parent `li`, the it would simply be:

```
$("#li" + idNo + " .Skill").css("background-color", "#790000");
```